# Moving in Unity3d C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

just a little question regarding moving in Unity3d.

Here's what I have so far

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class move : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveSpeed;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        moveSpeed = 10f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        transform.Translate(moveSpeed*Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")*Time.deltaTime,0f,moveSpeed*Input.GetAxis("Vertical")*Time.deltaTime); 
    }
}
```

Basically, I have a cube that I control using arrows or WASD. When I press Left or Right, it just moves cube to the left, rather than smoothly turning. Question is, how do I make it turn to the right and left, rather than go there?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seriously, [Translate & Rotate](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/translate-and-rotate?playlist=17117), 13th lesson of Unity's scripting

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Forgot that I need to use Rotate instead of Transform. Thanks!

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

Answer (score 2):

Translate is for position movement, to rotate you need to use [Rotate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html)